# How to capture the node name in load runner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have 4 nodes application server  (Node 1,2,3 & 4) When ever i run the script the request goes to one of that node. How do i capture to which node the request goes in load runner?

Comment: Unless the server somehow responds with the node ID you cannot know

Comment: Is there anyway it can be enabled to show up in the response?

Comment: Depends on the server logic. Usually it is not shown anywhere.

Comment: Help us to understand how the selection for which node is made?